# Multi-property sort is inverting elements

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to implement a multiple-property sort on some data and approached the problem by doing back-to-back `stable_sorts`:

```
bool DecreasingA(const Data & a, const Data & b) {
    return a.A >= b.A;
}

bool DecreasingB(const Data & a, const Data & b) {
    if (a.B)
        return true;  // if a.B is true, maintain ordering
    if (b.B)
        return false; // a.B is false, but b.B is true, to swap elements
    return true;      // a.B and b.B are false, maintain ordering
}

std::vector<Data> myVector;

// add Data to vector here

std::stable_sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), DecreasingA());
std::stable_sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), DecreasingB());
```

But after I do this, `myVector` has the A property in the opposite order that I want. Even though it was correctly sorted after the first `stable_sort`

For Example:

Before the sorting:

```
A B C

1 0 5
1 1 8
2 0 2
0 1 3
```

After first sort (Decreasing A) looks good:

```
A B C

2 0 2
1 0 5
1 1 8
0 1 3
```

After second sort (Decreasing B) I get this:

```
A B C

0 1 3
1 1 8
1 0 5
2 0 2
```

Instead of what I want:

```
A B C

1 1 8
0 1 3
2 0 2
1 0 5
```

I am thinking it is an issue with my `DecreasingB` function, but I have tried all sorts of logic and keep getting this inversion. Any suggestions?

I know I could write one compare function to handle this particular situation, but I need flexibility for the end user to select which properties to sort and in what order they are applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison functions are both broken. Neither implements the necessary strict weak ordering that `std::stable_sort` requires. Specifically,

- Irreflexivity: `f(x, x)` must be false.
- Antisymmetry : `f(x, y)` implies `!f(y, x)`

Your functions fail on both accounts.

You probably want this instead:

```
bool DecreasingA(const Data & a, const Data & b) {
    return a.A > b.A;  // > instead of >=
}

bool DecreasingB(const Data & a, const Data & b) {
    if (a.B == b.B)   // both equal, so a does not precede b
        return false;
    if (b.B)          // b.B is true and a.B is false, so a does not precede b
        return false; 
    return true;      // a.B is true and b.B is false, so a does precede b
}
```

Comment: is it safe to define a function IncreasingA as !DecreasingA(a,b) then? (same with IncreasingB)

Comment: @Moop: It would be safe with the way `DecreasingA` is incorrectly defined now, because the inverse of `>=` is `<`, which is an appropriate ordering operator. But if you correctly define `DecreasingA`, then no, you cannot define `IncreasingA` as `!DecreasingA`. However, you can define it by reversing the arguments. i.e. `Increasing(a,b)` can be defined as `Decreasing(b,a)`.

Comment: I tested it and [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc7b344b0aa8dc54). However, it's far from obvious on first reading, plus it requires two passes over the data. I'd prefer my `std::tie` trick which delegates to lexicographical comparison and uses only one pass. +1 though.

Comment: btw, `return a.B > b.B` also gives the desired output.

Comment: @TemplateRex I need the flexibility though this example provides. Your answer is good but when you have ~6-7 properties you cannot define all permutations easily. If there is a way to dynamically create the compare function on-the-fly to suit my needs, then yes, one pass is ideal.

Comment: @Moop yes, in that case it is more flexible, see my updated answer.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Yes, true. However, this verbose version better demonstrates what a strict weak ordering is.

Comment: @Moop `" If there is a way to dynamically create the compare function on-the-fly to suit my needs, then yes, one pass is ideal."` lambda? `std::stable_sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [](const Data & a, const Data & b){ return std::tie(a.B, a.A) > std::tie(b.B, b.A); })`

Comment: @doc I meant, sort by Decreasing A then by Increasing B then by Increasing D etc..

Comment: I would think that it's far easier to show that `>` satisfies the axioms of SWO than two ifs and an else case :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write a `DecreasingBThenA`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Data
{
    int A, B, C;    
};

bool DecreasingBThenA(const Data & a, const Data & b) 
{
    return std::tie(a.B, a.A) > std::tie(b.B, b.A);
}

int main()
{    
    auto myVector = std::vector<Data> 
    {{ 1, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 8}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 3}};

    std::stable_sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), DecreasingBThenA);

    for (auto&& t : myVector)
        std::cout << "{" << t.A << ", " << t.B << ", " << t.C << "}\n";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1501ad178d3087bc) that produces your desired output.

If you have `N` elements in your `Data`, and you want to be able to do arbitrary sortings, then indeed all you need is `DecreasingA` through `DecreasingN` comparisons (each returning `a.X > b.X` for data member `X`), and you then do multiple passes using `std::sort` in the *reverse order* of the criteria that you want it sorted. So `BThenA` requires first sorting on `A` then on `B`. This is the same way as you would sort data in Excel on various columns simultaneously using the column-wise sort button.

Comment: But I have already sorted the A member, so B doesn't need to know about it. It just needs to preserve the ordering. Also, I mentioned in my post that I could do this, but I have a ~6-7 properties that can be sorted on in any order.

Comment: Isn't that the reason its a stable sort? So it preserves the input ordering if two things are equal?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do what OP wants. If you take a look at expected output it's not simply `A` greater than `B` (e.g. `1 1 8` goes before `2 0 2`).

Comment: I think you should change `tie(a.A, a.B)` to `tie(a.B, a.A)` and tie b respectively. Haha yeah you updated answer when I was writing this comment.

Answer (score 1):

`DecreasingA` does not provide a strict weak ordering as required by the sorting algorithms and thus any particular behavior is not guaranteed.